# Visited state/class on div not anchor using React Js

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to add a visited state/class on a Div by using state, but running into some issues. I am not able to use an anchor, so I need to be able to set it on a class.

This is not an option:

```
a:visited {
  ...
}
```

Codesandbox.io:
https://codesandbox.io/s/l5x1l78mqz

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what issues you are running into? I don't think it's entirely clear what you're trying to get happen and what's happening instead.

Comment: I guess he want to add class to visited link to notify that it has been clicked before.

Comment: I am trying to add a visited class on a div and not anchor. I understand I can do by using a pseudo class. However, I need another way to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store this information in some state variable. You could store this right on `BreadCrumb`, but to do that you'd need to (1) make it a class and (2) handle its click function natively before calling `onClickTabItem`:

```
class BreadCrumb extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {visited: false}
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <li className={this.state.visited ? "visited" : ""} ... >
    );
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can store the visited state information in `SummaryBar` so that you can pass the visited status in as a prop, as it seems you are attempting to do. To do this you need a data structure that allows you to store *all* the visited states, not just the currently selected one.

```
state = { activeTab: 0, select: "" , visited: {}};
```

Then in `handleClickTabItem`, you updated the `visited` for the given element (which you'd need to figure out the title for)

```
visited = this.state.visited;
visited[title] = true;
this.setState(visited: visited);
```

To figure out the title, the easiest way is probably to pass it as an arg to the click handler in `BreadCrumb`

```
onClick={() => onClickTabItem(title)}
```

You can then use this in your `Buttons` function as you are attempting to do:

```
visited={this.state.visited[title]}
```

Comment: Not sure I am understanding your logic. Here is an updated codsandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/2wnyl1kp80

Comment: I see you'd taking the first of the two options. So you need to (1) Add `state` in the `BreadCrumb` class that remembers if it was visited or not, and (2) handle the click in `BreadCrumb` itself to update that state before passing the message up to the parent, and (3) use css that will style your item according to the result of your new `BreadCrumb` logic.

Comment: Check it out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/32oj3w132m -- here i'm using a new "visited" class (similar to you were adding a "visit" class in your last example), and added css to make any "visited" class item have a blue background.

Comment: Thanks Legend!!!! Yeah, I wasn’t comparing to this.state.vistied in my conditional...Good looking out 

Comment: one question tho, how is 'onClickTabItem' being passed as props? Even if I comment it out it still fires. Kinda of weird behavior

Comment: So in this example, I'm managing the visited state entirely in `BreadCrumb` via its state (line 7, `setState`). Calling `onClickTabItem` is entirely unnecessary for keeping track of `visited`. But I still call it because that's what tells the parent to set `active`. It could start getting confusing to keep track of visited in one place and active in another, but that's a choice up to you. If you wanted to keep track of `visited` and `active` in the same place, then I'd try option 2, above, where you keep an object in the parent, e.g. `visited = {one: true, two: false, three: true, four: true}`

Comment: The only problem is its essentialy does the same thing as add the activetab. It should be adding the blue background class to the previous clicked element.

Comment: So change the logic to if(active) / else if (visited) / else, that way the current active tab will not have blue, but any previously visited tab will